# Spring boot eureka - remove dead services

Tags: netflix-eureka, spring-cloud-netflix

I am researching about Eureka for services discovery and I found out that if I kill a process, eureka displays it as "DOWN". Will it clean it and remove it on it's own someday?

The scenario is this:  Lets say I am working with amazon AWS. I want to upload a new version this way: prepare X new machines and kill the old ones.

The new machines will register to eureka on startup, but how will the old machines be unregistered from Eureka?

I use java and spring-cloud.

Thanks,
Ido

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if this will help you but you can try this.

Eureka server application.yml

```
eureka:
  server:
    enableSelfPreservation: false
```

Service application.yml

```
eureka:
  instance:
    leaseRenewalIntervalInSeconds: 1
    leaseExpirationDurationInSeconds: 2
```

Read this for info:- https://github.com/ExampleDriven/spring-cloud-eureka-example